# Add work items on behalf of issue assignee in YouTrack workflow

Tags: workflow, youtrack

In YouTrack, there is standard workflow named "jetbrains-youtrack-workTimer", which automatically adds work items to issues.

Here's the code which adds work:

```
issue.applyCommand(l10n(add work Today{days+" "}d{hours+" "}h{minutes+" "}m)+" "+l10n(The work item automatically added by the timer.));
```

The problem is, it always adds work items on behalf of project owner, not the issue assignee. It is not convenient because most developers only have rights to change their own work items.

So, how can I add work item "on behalf" of issue assignee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to set or change the work item author in the current version (6.0); see the backlog issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-24695